# vaadin. A lot of warnings: Failed to define class ... from Service Module Loader

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, vaadin6

vaadin 6.8.13

My application works normally. But during application work vaadin is showing a lot of warnings in console.

Is there any possibility to disable this warnings without adding gwt library?
Example of warning:

```
16:09:27,342 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed to define class com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.ShortcutActionHandler$ShortcutActionHandlerOwner in Module "deployment.vaadin_1.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/ShortcutActionHandler$ShortcutActionHandlerOwner (Module "deployment.vaadin_1.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasWidgets from [Module "deployment.vaadin_1.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This error will happen when we use JBOSS AS - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/169575?tstart=0

**Reason:** Some or all classes in gwt-user.jar required for compiling the Vaadin client side widgets are loaded by the JBoss AS unnecessarily.

**Fix:** Include gwt-user.jar to the deployment package in WEB-INF/lib folder with the vaadin.jar.

References - [Deploy vaadin to JBoss 7.0 gives me a ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189102/deploy-vaadin-to-jboss-7-0-gives-me-a-classnotfoundexception)